# Excel decimal separator behaves differently based on regional setting

Tags: excel, decimalformat, vba

I have an excel which there are some values with decimals.
The values are **strings**, and since many countries are using it, some countries use "," comma for decimal places, others use "." dot for decimal places.

Once all the data worldwide is compiled, people from different regional areas process the data with macros.

In order for people to use same settings, I change in the macro their decimalseparator to be all the same:

```
Application.UseSystemSeparators = False
Application.DecimalSeparator = ","
application.ThousandsSeparator = "."
```

I then run certain macros to add the values together and this is where the problem begins.
For people in europe the macro works perfectly.
The macro first converts any dots to commas like this (note that the cell value is a string):

```
If InStr(NW.Cells(ttt, 100), ".") > 0 Then
       x2 = Replace(NW.Cells(ttt, 100), ".", ",")
       NW.Cells(ttt, 100) = x2
End If
```

So if NW.Cells(ttt, 100) = 12.25 it converts it to 12,25 then it runs further macros (adding all values together).

But if a person in USA runs the macro, the 12.25 becomes 1225

Since I have changed the application.decimalsepator to "," at the beginning of the macro, I don't understand why the macro behaves differently...

Any ideas how to solve this ?

Note Excel 2007 and Excel 2010 is being used so cannot use the =NUMBERVALUE function...

thanks

Comment: I think the main problem is "The values are strings" this is where you should start to solve your problem. If the values are values then there is no issue switching the localization. Where do these "string-values" come from?

Comment: Why not just implement a `NUMBERVALUE` function in VBA, and use that?

Comment: @Peh, reason for values being strings is because data is saved on the background on a Mysql database...on one MYSQL field I saved various excel cells, so there is a combination of strings and values added together as strings...

I then convert it back to values when retrieved from MySQL database.

The values and strings are entered worldwide, so they come from different countries, some using commas, some using dots...

Comment: @Ron, How do I implement a NUMBERVALUE function ?

Comment: I would lookup the current `.DecimalSeparator` of the system that is running the import to Excel and convert it to that DecimalSeparator before input.

Comment: Since VBA will default to US regional settings whenever possible, I'd suggest you reverse your approach and convert commas to decimal points.

Comment: @Rory, seems like your suggestion is working (I haven't thoroughly tested it yet). Are you saying that VBA on the background uses USA settings even if regional settings on the PC are European ?

Comment: Yes. If you pass a date *string* in VBA for example, it will be interpreted in US format, if possible, no matter where you are.

Comment: Mate, just tested as German settings then as USA settings...in both cases I get the same result, which means your are right!  Thanks so much for sharing your knowledge (and thanks everyone for trying to help me)

Comment: Some countries use the period for thousands separator and comma for the decimal point.  Some use the single quote mark for the thousands separator and a comma for the decimal point.  Others use the single quote for the thousands separator and the period for the decimal point.  In all cases, single quotation marks should be changed to commas.  The if the third character from the right is a comma, then change it to a period.  I think that will solve your problem.

Comment: @user1135218 Determine the decimal separator being used; split the number on that separator (and remove the digit grouping symbol, if any); values to the left are integer portion; values to the right are decimal portion (divide by 10^number_of_digits).  Add the two together and output as a double.

Answer (score 0):

```
Sub changeSeparators()
Dim myRange As Range
Dim rng As Range

Set myRng = ActiveSheet.Range("A1:A500")

For Each rng In myRng
   rng.Value = Replace(rng.Value, "'", ",")
   If Left(Right(rng.Value, 3), 1) = "," Then
       rng.Value = Mid(rng.Value, 1, Len(rng.Value) - 3) & "." & Right(rng.Value, 2)
   End If
Next rng
End Sub
```

Comment: thank you for sharing. I will test your code too in case values do have thousands separators. It has not been the case so far but might possible in future and will be affected.